# Django-rest-auth : How refresh Token?

Tags: django, django-rest-auth

I'm using Django-rest-auth for authentication (https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io).
but when I register a new account, the api sent back to me a Token who never change after.
For more security, how can I do to have a new token every time I login ?

Comment: You can use the [JWT support](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which provide this feature among others.

Comment: JWT support has a nice feature to encode JWT token with individual user's secret code. You can make token short lived and after use refresh token. As you have mentioned to use different token, I think these all tokens will still be valid. So, you cannot improve the security just by returning different token for a user since these token are signed by same key.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with an API, please structure your code in such a way.

```
class LoginAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginFormSerializer

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request):
       serializer = LoginFormSerializer(data=request.data)
       if not serializer.is_valid():
          return error_message(message=MessageKey.ERROR_MISSING_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD.value)

       username = serializer.data['username']
       password = serializer.data['password']
       try:
           user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
           if not user:
              return error_message(message=MessageKey.ERROR_INVALID_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD.value)
           if user.record_status == RecordStatus.ACTIVE.name:
              # Create a new auth token using your token service
              auth_token = create_auth_token(user)
            
              user_serializer = UserSerializer(user)
              user_data = user_serializer.data
              user_data['auth_token'] = str(auth_token[0])
              data = generate_user_account_profile(language, user, user_data)
              return success_message(data=data)
           else:
             return error_message(MessageKey.ERROR_INVALID_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD.value)
        except Exception as ex:
           traceback.print_exc()
           return error_message(MessageKey.ERROR_DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE.value)
```

The function create_auth_token(user) can be structured as folloows;

```
def create_auth_token(user):
    """
    This is used to create or update an auth token
    :param user:
    :return:
    """
    try:
        token = Token.objects.filter(user=user)
        if not token:
            token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        else:
            token = Token.objects.filter(user=user)
            new_key = token[0].generate_key()

            # Encrypt random string using SHA1
            sha1_algorithm = hashlib.sha1()
            sha1_algorithm.update(new_key.encode('utf-8'))
            first_level_value = sha1_algorithm.hexdigest()

            # Encrypt random string using MD5
            md5_algorithm = hashlib.md5()
            md5_algorithm.update(first_level_value.encode('utf-8'))
            second_level_value = md5_algorithm.hexdigest()

            token.update(key=second_level_value)
        return token
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error(msg=f'Failed to create auth token {ex}', stacklevel=logging.CRITICAL)
        pass
```

**Note: This can be adjusted to fit in any place of your choice i.e you can adjust it to work in your view.py file, services, etc**